# Is there a way to add comments to a linker script?

Tags: linker-scripts

My question is very simple. Is there a way to add comments to a linker script? Like for example in a makefile:

```
# Comment
```

Answer (score 7):

You may include comments in linker scripts just as in C, delimited by `'/*'` and `'*/'`. As in C, comments are syntactically equivalent to whitespace.

Directly from the docs:
https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.25/ld/Script-Format.html#Script-Format